# Representing existing HTML as Backbone.js data structures in CoffeeScript

Tags: backbone.js, coffeescript

I'm having a rough time wrapping my head around this.

I have an HTML list, and I want to use Backbone.js to handle events on those list items. Here's what I've got so far. This is a simplified scenario to help me better understand how to structure a larger application. For my example, I simply want to ingest an existing HTML list into the Backbone structure, and handle click events through the Backbone view.

I'm getting an error related to using @model in the view, but I'm fairly certain I'm misunderstanding things conceptually here.

CoffeeScript:

```
$ ->
    class Item extends Backbone.Model
        name: null

    class ItemList extends Backbone.Collection
        model: Item

    class ItemView extends Backbone.View
        tagName: 'li'

        initialize: =>
            @model.bind('change', this.render)
            @model.view = this

        events:
            'click' : 'clicked'

        clicked: -> 
            console.log 'clicked'

        render: =>
            this

    class ItemListView extends Backbone.View
        el: $('ul#test')

        initialize: =>
            $('li', @el).each(@addItem)

        addItem: (item) ->
            item = new ItemView({ el: item })

        render: =>
            this

    Items = new ItemListView
```

HTML:

```
<ul id="test">
    <li>Hi thar</li>
    <li>Yeah</li>
    <li>OK</li>
</ul>
```

Here's a jsfiddle I started earlier: http://jsfiddle.net/Saxx4/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I never really like CoffeeScript (Javascript is so nice, why replace it?), but it looks like there are a few issues here:

- You're getting an error on `@model` because you never set it on the `ItemView`. This doesn't happen automatically - you have to either instantiate the view's model in `initialize()` or pass it into the constructor, e.g.:

  ```
  addItem: (item) ->
      model = new ItemView({ 
          el: item, 
          model: new Item({ 
              // assuming you might want the list item text
              // in the model data
              text: $(item).text() 
          }) 
      })
  ```
- You usually just want to specify a selector in `el`, not a jQuery object - otherwise the DOM might not be ready when you load your Backbone code: `el: '#test'`
- You need to pass an options object to the `ItemListView` constructor, not just a single argument, no matter what you do in `initialize()`:

  ```
  class ItemListView extends Backbone.View

      initialize: (opts) =>
          opts.items.each(@addItem)

      // ...

  Items = new ItemListView({ items: $('ul#test li') })
  ```

Comment: Playing with this now - definitely starting to click. Switching back to JS until I better understand how Backbone works.

Comment: OK, switching back to JS: http://jsfiddle.net/nicksergeant/b2RUW/ -- getting "Cannot read property '0' of undefined"

Comment: Ahh, got it. Needed to reference "this" in addItem instead of passing item through